# binary search using for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

I am trying to implement binary search using for loop in javascript but it fails some of the test cases, below is my code

```
function binarySearch(arr, val){
    let start = 0
    let end = arr.length - 1
    let middle = Math.floor((start + end)/2)

    for(let i = start; i<= end; i++){
        if(val === arr[middle]) { 
           return middle
        }

        if(val < arr[middle]){
            end = middle - 1
        }

        if(val > arr[middle]){
           start = middle + 1
        }

        middle = Math.floor((start + end)/2)
    }
        return -1
  }

    // test case:1 console.log(binarySearch([5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 18, 30, 34, 35, 37, 40, 44, 64, 79, 84, 86, 95, 96, 98, 99], 9))
    
    
   // test case:2 console.log(binarySearch([1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10], 10))
```

It passes the 2nd test case but miserably fails the 1st one. Can anyone throw some light, please?

Comment: Looks like you have a typo. `val > middle` should be `val > arr[middle]`.

Comment: `if(val > middle)`?

Comment: @Ouroborus while your suggestion is correct but the problem is still going to persist. I realized why not use "for loop" in this case. It is because inside the loop I'm assigning start a new value but problems arise when you realize that the value of "i" remains the same initially initialized start value. The same occurs with i <= end. I mean "i" is not reassigned anything other than i++. I've realized the fact that under these situations better go with while loop iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized why not use "for loop" in this case.

It is because inside the loop I'm assigning "start" a new value but problems arise when you come across the fact that the value of "i" remains the same previously initialized "start" value.

The same occurs with, i <= end

I mean "i" is not reassigned anything other than i++. I've realized the fact that under these situations it's better to go with the while loop iteration instead of for loop where you need to reinitialize index from inside the loop.

Comment: You can use a for-loop if you want, but you'll have to structure it differently. https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/283eb9fa223fe8b6835c1cd9e3e9726c

Answer (score 1):

Just like you said Nishant, a While-loop would be suitable in this case, because you should update the values of left(start), right(end) and middle indexes inside the loop.

Iterative implementation of Binary Search (in Java):

```
public int binarySearch(int[] array, int target) {
    var left = 0;
    var right = array.length - 1;

    while (left <= right) { 
        var middle = (left + right) / 2;

        if (array[middle] == target)
            return middle;

        if (target < array[middle]) 
            right = middle - 1;
        else
            left = middle + 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class BinarySearch {

```
public static int findElement(int[] arr,int target){

    int start=0;
    int end=arr.length-1;

    for(int i=start; i<=end;i++ ){
        int mid=start+(end-start)/2;
        if(arr[mid]==target){
            return mid;
        }else if(arr[mid]<target){
            start=mid+1;
        }else if(arr[mid]>target){
            end=mid-1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String [] ar){

    int [] arr={5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 18, 30, 34, 35, 37, 40, 44, 64, 79, 84, 86, 95, 96, 98, 99};

    int target=9;

    int index=findElement(arr,target);

    if(index==-1){
        System.out.println("Element not found");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Element found at index: "+index);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know js but I know Java so I'm presenting my implementation of binary search using for loop as follows:

```
int bSearch(int arr[],int x) {
   int index = 0;
   for(int i = arr.length >> 1; i >= 1; i>>=1)
       while((index + i < arr.length) && (arr[index + i] <= x)) 
           index+=i;

    return(arr[index] == x) ? index : -1;
}
```

How it works??

Consider `i` as mid and `index` as lower bound of binary search.

If u notice carefully, you'll find that in binary search, everytime the mid starts with arr.length divided by 2 and after every iteration, it gets divided by 2 and a last step, it reaches it's minimum value i.e. 1.

So in for loop I've implemented the same.
But those who are wondering what is:

```
int i = arr.length >> 1;
```

It actually means:

`int i = arr.length / 2;`

And same for

`i>>=1`

It is same as:

`i /= 2;` or `i = i / 2;`

Now at the while loop part, the first condition checks that if we add `index` with `i` , will it go out of the boundary of array or not. The second condition checks whether `x` lies in between `index`(lower bound) and `i` (mid). If it's true then we don't need to add `index` with `i` but if it's not the case then :

`x` lies after `i`(mid) so we are adding `index`(lower bound) with `i`(mid).

This part of code highlighted in traditional binary search:

```
int bSearch(int arr[], int x) {
int lowerBound = 0;
int upperBound = array.length - 1;

    while (left <= right) { 
        int middle = (lowerBound + upperBound) / 2;

        if (array[middle] == x)
            return middle;
        
        // *look at this condition carefully*

        if (x > array[middle])
            lowerBound = middle + 1; 
        else
            upperBound = middle - 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Notice the following line:

```
if(x > arr[middle])
  lowerBound = middle + 1;
```

The above code can be also written as:

```
if(arr[middle + lowerBound] <= x)
   lowerBound += middle;
```

Now if `x` is present in the array and array is sorted then `index` should have the index of `x` and return it else otherwise, it will return `-1`.